# ContextualCompositionHost In Quartz Execute (Background Process)

Tags: asp.net, mef, quartz.net, httpcontext

I have this method to periodically sending notification message:

```
Public Overrides Sub Execute(context As Quartz.IJobExecutionContext)
    Try
        Logger.Write("NotificationJob execute start")
        _service = ContextualCompositionHost.Container.GetExportedValue(Of IMessageService)()
        _service.SendMessages()
        Logger.Write("NotificationJob execute end")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Logger.Write("NotificationJob error: " + ex.Message + ", " + ex.StackTrace)
    End Try
End Sub
```

`ContextualCompositionHost.Container` work well when used in `Global.asax` or `WebControls`, but the object does not created on above code, the `WebScope`

```
Public Enum WebScopeMode
    Application
    Request
End Enum
```

Error occured on the following method in [ScopedContainerHttpModule](http://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/28783234):

```
Private Sub SetUpRequestLevelContainerCreation()
     ContextualCompositionHost.Initialize(Function() HttpContext.Current.Items, AddressOf CreateRequestContainer)
End Sub
```

`HttpContext.Current` is `Nothing`.

Anyone know why and how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Quartz.Net jobs run in the .Net threadpool, not on the thread that schedules the job, so there is no http context when your job is run. You should pass in all the data your job will need in the  job data map when you schedule the job.